# Output items one by one from JavaScript array to HTML text on an interval

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

First JavaScript attempt. Created an array of words that I would like to output to an #id element in HTML.  Would like the words to cycle through in order, and one at a time on an interval. At the end of the array.length, I would love for the words to stop on the second item [1].

Successfully used code I found to make the words randomly cycle, but I'd really like to make them cycle in order, and stop on item [1].

```
var arr = new Array ("dog.", "owner.", "partner.", "community.", "park.", "baby.", "neighbor.", "friend.", "family.", "vet.", "grandparent.", "party.");

var i = 0;

function nextItem() {
  i = i + 1;
  i = i % arr.length;
  return arr[0];  
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  document.getElementById('rotate').textContent = arr[0];
});

setInterval(nextItem, 500);
```

I expected the code to cycle through the items, but I only see item [1] flicker, then item [0] appear and stay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should assign the call to setInterval to a variable - this way you can stop the interval as soon as you're through the array. Inside the **nextItem** function you can decide what happens if incrementing the **i** variable exceeds the size of the array. In case it does set it to 1 and clear the interval.

Here's an example:

```js
var arr = new Array("dog.", "owner.", "partner.", "community.", "park.", "baby.", "neighbor.", "friend.", "family.", "vet.", "grandparent.", "party.");

var i = 0;
var interval;

function nextItem() {
  if (i + 1 < arr.length) {
    i += 1;
  } else {
    i = 1;
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  document.getElementById('rotate').textContent = arr[i];
}

interval = setInterval(nextItem, 500);
document.getElementById('rotate').textContent = arr[i];
```

```html
<p id="rotate"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `nextItem` function, you wan to return `arr[i]` not `arr[0]`. Additionally, you need to add some conditional logic that checks if your index variable `i` is equal to 1.